# I am not sure why I am getting a "Compile Error: Method or data member not found" for my code in VBA. It's highlighting "Sub AcronymParser()"

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Sub AcronymParser()

    'Declare variables
    Dim AcronymList As New Collection
    Dim Acronym As String
    Dim Definition As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Doc As Document
    Dim AcroTable As Table
    
    'Set the document object
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument

    'Iterate through the document and find all acronyms
    For Each Rng In Doc.Words
        If Rng.Font.Bold And Rng.Characters(1).Font.AllCaps And Rng.Characters(2).Font.AllLower Then
            'Add the acronym to the list, along with its definition
            Acronym = Rng.Text
            Definition = Rng.Next.Text
            AcronymList.Add Definition, Acronym
        End If
    Next Rng

    'Create a new table
    Set AcroTable = Doc.Tables.Add(Range:=Doc.Content, NumRows:=AcronymList.Count + 1, NumColumns:=2)

    'Set the column widths
    AcroTable.Columns(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(1), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
    AcroTable.Columns(2).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=InchesToPoints(3), RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone

    'Add the headings for the table
    AcroTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Acronym"
    AcroTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = "Definition"

    'Iterate through the acronym list and add the acronyms and definitions to the table
    For i = 1 To AcronymList.Count
        AcroTable.Cell(i + 1, 1).Range.Text = AcronymList.Keys(i - 1)
        AcroTable.Cell(i + 1, 2).Range.Text = AcronymList(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I tried the above script with the expectation that it would run. For some reason, I keep getting the same error. Not sure what to do here.

Comment: `AllLower` is not a property of `Font`, maybe you want `SmallCaps`?

Comment: Usually, when the procedure signature is highlighted in yellow, 'another thing' (e.g. an undeclared variable) is highlighted in blue. What's the 'other thing'?

Comment: ... also, the `i` variable is not declared (`Dim i As Long`).

Comment: If you don't use [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) then consider to use it, it is very helpfull.

Comment: Agree with use of Option Explicit. It would help us help you if you could include a link to a sample document on which using the macro draws the error. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258  Also, AllCaps and SmallCaps are not the equivalent of Upper Case and Lower Case. They are different font formatting.

Comment: Also, **Bold** is a *toggle* attribute and it is possible to have text in a document appear to be not bold with **Bold** character formatting or appear to be bold without **Bold** character formatting. That depends on the formatting of the underlying paragraph style. I.E. if the underlying paragraph style is bold, and the bold attribute is applied to text within the paragraph, it will appear not bold but will have a bold character attribute.

Comment: You may be interested in: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/42313-acronym-definiton-list-generator.html and/or https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/12090-need-macro-make-list-defined-terms.html